# Two surnames in HL7 PID-5 Segment

Tags: hl7

How do we go about writing a PID-5 segment (in HL7 V2) for a patient who has two surnames that are not hyphenated? Could we use a space in between the two surnames? For example: A patient's name is Jessica Marie Lewis Williams.

Could we write the field as: Lewis Williams^Jessica? Or would it be Lewis~Williams^Jessica?

Answer (score 3):

Usually, this is |Lewis Williams^Jessica|, which is valid. It's not valid to put repeats in a component like this: |Lewis~Williams^Jessica|

In some jurisdications - Spanish, German, Portuguese - other rules may apply, but you seem not be asking in one of those contexts